# Howto detect if a folder is writable with Android Version 4.4.2 ( KITKAT )

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

With KITKAT 4.4.2 I get a `EACCES permission denied` when trying to write a file to a specific Folder. I know the new policy with Kitkat and I should use only the primary external storage path

Because a lot of users have already installed my app and stored data in different folders I like to figure out if a path is writeable or not.

I already simply tried to check this with `file.canwrite()`. This method `returns true`, even my app is not able to write to that path.

How can I detect if a directory is writeable with KITKAT?

Comment: Why don't you add a READ permission and go on?

Comment: @Doctoror Drive: As the question mentoins it is a write topic. I do write into a dqatabase or I like to unzip a file. I can't write with a read permission. The question is regarding howto detect if a folder is writeable.

Comment: For KitKat and onward, I am still getting the same behavior. file.canWrite() returns true for the folders residing in SDcard (external removable storages). How did you solved this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Sorry that was a mistake from my side. 
It can be detected with file.canwrite().

Comment: Okay, sounds like it's not a reproducible problem then, so we should probably close or delete the question - but congratulations on fixing it.

Answer (score 2):

From my side, it can't be detected with file.canWrite().
The path of the external sdcard is /sdcard1